# 'RNPermissionsModule' could not be found. Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-permissions, react-native-permissions

I am trying to build an application that opens a camera after asking for permission. I am using 'react-native-permissions' and it seems that it cannot find the RNPermissionsModule. I am testing it on an android phone. Currently, I have v4.0.4 of 'react-native-permissions'

Here is another error that's connected with the main issue:
`[TypeError: Cannot read property 'PERMISSIONS' of undefined]`

Here is my Permissions.js

```
import { Alert, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { check, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS, request, openSettings } from 'react-native-permissions';

export const isIOS = Platform.OS === 'ios';

function showAlert(msg) {
    Alert.alert('', msg, [
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
            style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
            text: 'Settings',
            onPress: () => {
                openSettings().catch(() => console.warn('cannot open settings'));
            },
        },
    ]);
}

const hasCameraPermission = async (withAlert = true) => {
    try {
        const permission = isIOS
            ? PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA
            : PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA;
        const response = await check(permission);
        let camera;
        if (response.camera !== RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            camera = await request(permission);
        }
        if (camera === RESULTS.DENIED || camera === RESULTS.BLOCKED) {
            if (withAlert) {
                showAlert(
                    'Permission not granted for Camera. Unable to use camera in this application.',
                );
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
    }
};

const hasPhotoPermission = async (withAlert = true) => {
    try {
        const permission = isIOS
            ? PERMISSIONS.IOS.PHOTO_LIBRARY
            : PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_StorageService;
        const response = await check(permission);
        let photo;
        if (response.photo !== RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            photo = await request(permission);
        }
        if (photo === RESULTS.DENIED || photo === RESULTS.BLOCKED) {
            if (withAlert) {
                showAlert(
                    'Permission not granted for photos. Unable to get photos in this application.',
                );
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
    }
};

const PermissionsService = {
    hasCameraPermission,
    hasPhotoPermission,
}

export default PermissionsService;
```

Here's what I have tried:

- Reinstalling 'react-native-permissions'
- Downgrading 'react-native-permissions'
- cleaning the cache
- Check if RNPermissionsModule is registered using

```
const { NativeModules } = require('react-native');

  if (NativeModules.RNPermissionsModule) {
    console.log('RNPermissionsModule is registered!');
  } else {
    console.log('RNPermissionsModule not found');
  }
```

Output: RNPermissionsModule not found